# Glassfish: how to compile-on-time JSPs?

Tags: java, glassfish, weblogic

I am usually using Oracle WebLogic as Java Application Server. It has an interesting feature: when launched with Eclipse, it compiles JSP at run-time, so everytime I change something in a JSP, I do not need to redeploy.
In Glassfish, I am required to redeploy everytime I make a change.
Is there a way to specify this behavior for Glassfish too?

Comment: Which version of GlassFish are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In GlassFish 3 there is an option `development` which, if set to `true` enables JSP files to be checked for modification. Check your `web.xml` or `default-web.xml`.

Comment: This is not particularly helpful, a documentation link, or something along those lines would be.

Answer (score 0):

- In your glassfish-web.xml that you'd package along with the .WAR, you should have `<property name="development" value="true"/>` set in `<jsp-config>` tag. More info available at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beatx.html
- When changing your JSP, make sure you are changing them in the right location. Glassfish holds two copies of the app - one as part of the domain directory, and another as part of instance directory. You will need to modify the one that's part of the instance directory.